# Insert record with auto generated id filed into multiple related tables in an async environment using Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables that are related to each other (simplified example):

`people`

```
id |  person
------------
1  | Peter
2  | Emma
3  | Sarah
```

`parents`

```
id_person | id_parent
---------------------
3         | 1
3         | 2
```

As you can see, `Sarah` is the daughter of `Peter` and `Emma`.

Now, how can I add `Sarah's` brother `Joe` into both tables if the `ids` in `people` are auto incremented and the queries are made in an async environment?

The reason why I mention *"the queries are made in an async environment"* is, because I'm afraid that a sequential approache which is done in multiple steps, such as this one:

- 1) - Insert `Joe` into `people`
- 2) - Read `Joe's` new `id` from `people`
- 3) - Insert `Joe's` new `id` into `parents`

might fail if another query from another thread/process/coroutine hits the DB inbetween `1)` and `2)`.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting `Joe`, retrieve the new `id` with [`last_insert_rowid()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html):

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

This is connection specific, so as long as other threads or processes use their own connection, this will work fine in an environment where many things go on at once.

Comment: Wouldn't this be very expensive? For example, if each query comes from a new coroutine and there are thousands of them? Sorry I didn't mention coroutines earlier.

Comment: Connections are usually pooled by the framework, so opening one is not expensive at all. Note that if two threads use the same connection at once, you'll get data corruption, the database is not designed for that.